# Unable to update my system Ubuntu13.04: Getting message - requires installation of untrusted packages

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I had been trying to update my Ubuntu13.04 via 'software updater'.
The updater messages that `the following needs to be installed. Press continue to install`
When I press continue , a window appears as shown in the attachment. There message appears: `requires installation of untrusted packages`
[image]

On pressing O.K. button, the window disappears and nothing happens.
How to then update my system with the updates that the `software updater` is reflecting?

Answer (score 1):

I had also this problem yesterday.

It is now gone today. So my guess is that was a problem on Ubuntu servers side which they apparently solved.

If you still have the issue, try to open the terminal (the application) and type the following commands, they will force a refresh of the repository and propose to upgrade all packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You might get prompted for a password which is your user password. And you might be requested to validate the upgrade (press Enter or 'Y' and then Enter).

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I am upgrading my system via command line or terminal using the commands you told. The issue remains with the GUI (software updater)

Comment: If you relaunch the GUI after the command line upgrade, do you still have the problem? (I understand that you might need to wait for the next time there is something to upgrade to answer) :-)

Comment: I had something new to upgrade. I relaunched the GUI to upgrade this time but the problem still remains. So, again I had to upgrade via command line. Not only for the distribution upgrade but I am not able to install any application via command line which requires installation from unauthenticated source. What has happened to my system!!! I tried installing `recordmydesktop` via `ubuntu software centre` but due to the said issue I couldn't install that way and then I had to do it by command line.

Comment: Just one mistake in my last comment above: By mistake I wrote `I am not able to install any application via command line ` but it should be `I am not able to install any application via GUI `